# Obtain access package from an Azure AD group id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to obtain the access package that a specific Azure AD group belongs to. I only have the groups Id.

Reading the documentation I suspect that I could do this by listing the access packages and using a filter in the query, but Im not sure how to build the filter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Codenoob, What do you mean by access package?

Comment: Hi, by access package I mean this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/accesspackage?view=graph-rest-beta and by group I mean this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Nice question, is this something possible from Azure portal? Any more answers Please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below api to get access package for particular group
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageCatalogs/catalogId/accessPackageResources?$filter=(originId eq 'Groupid')`

[image]

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorial-access-package-api#add-the-group-to-the-catalog) for more information

Comment: This only returns the "Access Package Resource" but it doesn't return the "Access Package" as was originally requested. I don't see an easy way to query what Access Packages contain the Access Package Resource.